# Salesforce Test Execution Zendesk error

Tags: apex, error, null-pointer

I've tried to execute the following test method:

```
static testMethod void testLeadStatusExistingDeal() {
    Test.startTest();

    Lead record = new Lead(LastName = 'Dimitrov', Company ='NewLead1', Monthly_Volume__c= '1234', Phone='1423542452', Website='www.google.com');
    insert record;
    System.debug('record ' + record);

    Contact contact = new Contact(LastName = 'Dimitrov', Company_Name__c = record.id, email = 'dylan@dylan.com');
    Contact contact1 = new Contact(LastName = 'Dimitrov', Company_Name__c = record.id, email = 'dilyan@dilyan.com');
    insert contact;
    insert contact1;

    Account account = new Account(name = 'acc1');
    insert account;

    ApexPages.StandardController c = new ApexPages.StandardController(record);
    LeadToMerchantController ltmc = new LeadToMerchantController(c);
    String leadStatusExistingDeal = ltmc.leadStatusExistingDeal(record);
    System.debug('leadStatusExistingDeal ' + leadStatusExistingDeal);
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

in my Salesforce sandbox but insted I received the following error. Here is the screenshot of the log:
[image: Salesforce Test Execution Zendesk error]

Could you please advise how to avoid the error and run my test method.

Regards,

Dilyan

Here is the code of the LeadToMerchantController class:

```
    public with sharing class LeadToMerchantController {

    Lead objLead;

    String objLeadId;

    public LeadToMerchantController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {    
        objLead = (Lead)controller.getRecord();
        System.debug('objLead ' + objLead.Id);   
    }

    public static String splitCompanyName(String company) {
        System.debug('company ' + company);
        String companyNameLowerCase = company.toLowerCase();
        List<Company_Extensions__c> extensions = Company_Extensions__c.getAll().values();
        Set<String> companyExtensions = new Set<String>();
        for(Company_Extensions__c extension : extensions) {
            companyExtensions.add(extension.Name);
            for(String companyExtension : companyExtensions){
                integer extIndex = companyNameLowerCase.indexOf(' ' + companyExtension);
                if(extIndex > -1) {
                    company = company.substring(0, extIndex);
                    companyNameLowerCase = companyNameLowerCase.substring(0, extIndex);    
                }
            }    
        }
        System.debug('companyNameLowerCase ' + companyNameLowerCase);
        System.debug('company ' + company);
        return company;        
    }

    public static String normalizeWebsite(String website) {
        System.debug('nrmWebsite ' + website);
        String normWebsite = '';
        if(website != null && !website.equals('')) {
            List<String> leadSplitWebsitesList = website.split('[,;]');                       
            String websiteSeparator = getUrlSeparator(website);
            System.debug('websiteSeparator ' + websiteSeparator);
            for(String leadSplitUrls :leadSplitWebsitesList) {
                leadSplitUrls = leadSplitUrls.toLowerCase();
                leadSplitUrls = NormalizationUtils.removePort(leadSplitUrls);
                leadSplitUrls = NormalizationUtils.addWWW(leadSplitUrls);
                leadSplitUrls = NormalizationUtils.removeDirectoryIndex(leadSplitUrls);
                leadSplitUrls = NormalizationUtils.removeDoubleSlashes(leadSplitUrls);
                normWebsite += leadSplitUrls;
                normWebsite += websiteSeparator;
                System.debug('normWebsite ' + normWebsite);
            }
            if(!websiteSeparator.equals('') && normWebsite.endsWith(websiteSeparator)) {
                // remove last symbol
                normWebsite = normWebsite.substring(0, normWebsite.length() - 1);
            }                         
        }    
        System.debug('normWebsite7 ' + normWebsite);
        return normWebsite;        
    }

    // Return separator of the urls
    // Return '' if the urls is empty or if the separator is not among the symbol ',' symbol  ';' sybmol ':' 
    public static string getUrlSeparator(String urls) {
        if(urls == null || urls.equals('')){
            return '';    
        }
        integer urlSeparator = urls.indexOf(',');
        if(urlSeparator > -1) {
            return ',';    
        }
        urlSeparator = urls.indexOf(';');
        if(urlSeparator > -1) {
            return ';';    
        }

        return '';
    }

    public static String normalizeEmail(String email){
        System.debug('email ' + email);
        String normalizedEmail = '';
        normalizedEmail = normalizedEmail.toLowerCase();
        if(normalizedEmail != null && !normalizedEmail.equals('')) {
            Integer atIndex = email.indexOf('@');
            if (atIndex > -1) {
                normalizedEmail = email.substring(0, atIndex);
            } else {
                normalizedEmail = email;
            }
        }    
        System.debug('normalizedEmail: ' + normalizedEmail);
        return normalizedEmail;
    }

    public static List<String> extractWebsites(String record) {
        List<String> patternWebsite = new List<String>();
        if(record == null || record.equals('')) {
            System.debug('record is null');
            return patternWebsite;
        }  
        String regexEncoding = '(https?://www.|https?|www.)([A-Za-z\\d._~:/?#\\[\\]@!$&\'()*+,;=-]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+[.][A-Za-z]{2,3}'; 
        Matcher websiteMatcher = Pattern.compile(regexEncoding).matcher(record);        
        while(websiteMatcher.find()) {
             // the matching value
            String entireUrl = websiteMatcher.group();
            if(entireUrl != null && !entireUrl.equals('')) {
                System.debug('entireUrl ' + entireUrl);            
                patternWebsite.add(entireUrl);                   
            }     
        }
        System.debug('patternWebsite: ' + patternWebsite); 
        return patternWebsite;
    }

    // Set status Existing Deal to the lead if  
    // 1. Lead company name coincide with Merchant company name; 
    // OR
    // 2. Some of the Lead websites coincide with some of the Merchant websites;
    // OR
    // 3. Some of the Lead emails coincide with some of the Merchant emails.
    // OR
    // 4. If merchant status is not one of the following Terminated/Cancelled/Lost Prospect/Rejected by Acquirer and Rejected by EMP.
    public String leadStatusExistingDeal(Lead leadObj) {
        String company = leadObj.Company;
        if(company != null && !company.equals('')) {
            System.debug('company_dilyan ' + company);
            company = splitCompanyName(company);
            System.debug('company_normalized ' + company);
            List<Account> accountCompanyList=[SELECT Name, id, Status__c FROM Account];
            List<Lead> updateLeadList = new List<Lead>();
                for(Account acc :accountCompanyList) {
                    String accountCompany = acc.Name;
                    System.debug('accountCompany_dilyan ' + accountCompany);
                    accountCompany = splitCompanyName(accountCompany);
                    System.debug('accountCompany_normalized ' + accountCompany);
                    String accountStatus = acc.Status__c;                    
                    if(accountCompany != null) {                            
                        if(accountCompany.equals(company)) {                                                       
                            if(!accountStatus.equals('Cancelled') && !accountStatus.equals('Lost Prospect') && !accountStatus.equals('Rejected by Acquirer') && !accountStatus.equals('Rejected by eMerchantPay') && !accountStatus.equals('Terminated')){
                                leadObj.Status__c = 'Existing Deal';
                                System.debug('leadObj4 ' + leadObj);
                                update leadObj;
                                String accountId = acc.Id;
                                System.debug('acc7 ' + acc);
                                System.debug('ld_M_7 ' + leadObj);
                                System.debug('1. Lead status is set to Existing Deal');
                                return accountId;
                            }    
                        }
                    }    
                }
            }

        String website = leadObj.Website;
        if(website != null && !website.equals('')) {        
            System.debug('website4 ' + website);
            List<String> leadWebsites = extractWebsites(website);
            System.debug('leadWebsites ' + leadWebsites);
            for (String leadUrl : leadWebsites) {
                System.debug('leadUrl ' + leadUrl);
                String normWebsite = normalizeWebsite(leadUrl);
                System.debug('normWebsite7 ' + normWebsite);
                String leadWebsite = normWebsite.trim();
                System.debug('leadWebsite ' + leadWebsite);
                List<String> leadSplitWebsitesList = leadWebsite.split('[,;\\s]');
                System.debug('leadSplitWebsitesList ' + leadSplitWebsitesList);
                List<Account> accountWebsiteList = [SELECT Url__c, Additional_Url__c, Status__c FROM Account];
                System.debug('accountWebsiteList ' + accountWebsiteList);
                List<Lead> updateLeadListURL = new List<Lead>();
                System.debug('updateLeadListURL ' + updateLeadListURL);
                if(accountWebsiteList != null) { 
                    for(Account acc :accountWebsiteList) {
                        String accountWebsite = acc.Url__c;
                        System.debug('accountWebsite1 ' + accountWebsite);
                        List<String> extractedAccountWebsite = extractWebsites(accountWebsite);                        
                        System.debug('extractedAccountWebsite ' + extractedAccountWebsite);
                        for(String accWebsite :extractedAccountWebsite) {
                            String accountSite = normalizeWebsite(accWebsite);
                            System.debug('accountWebsiteNormalized ' + accountSite);
                            String accountStatus = acc.Status__c;                        
                            if(accountSite != null) {
                                // List<String> accountSplitWebsitesList = accountWebsite.split('[,;]');   
                                // for(String accountSplitUrls :accountSplitWebsitesList) {
                                    for(String leadSplitUrls :leadSplitWebsitesList) {
                                        if(accountSite.equals(leadSplitUrls)) {
                                            if(!accountStatus.equals('Cancelled') && !accountStatus.equals('Lost Prospect') && !accountStatus.equals('Rejected by Acquirer') && !accountStatus.equals('Rejected by eMerchantPay') && !accountStatus.equals('Terminated')){
                                                leadObj.Status__c = 'Existing Deal';
                                                update leadObj;
                                                String accountId = acc.Id;
                                                System.debug('leadObj7 ' + leadObj);                                            
                                                System.debug('acc4 ' + accountId);
                                                System.debug('2. Lead status is set to Existing Deal');
                                                return accountId;
                                            }    
                                        }
                                    }
                                // }
                            }
                        }    
                    }                                  
                }
            }
        }

        List<Contact> leadContacts = [select id, company_name__c, email from contact where company_name__c = :leadObj.id];
        System.debug('leadContacts ' + leadContacts);
        List<Account> accountList = [SELECT name, id from Account];
        if (accountList.size() > 0) {
            for(Account objAccount :accountList) { 
                List<Merchant_To_Contact__c> accountContacts = [select id, Merchant_Name__c, email__c from Merchant_To_Contact__c where Merchant_Name__c =:objAccount.id];
                System.debug('accountContacts ' + accountContacts);
                Integer leadContactsSize = leadContacts.size();
                System.debug('leadContactsSize ' + leadContactsSize);
                Integer accountContactsSize = accountContacts.size();        
                System.debug('accountContactsSize ' + accountContactsSize);
                if(leadContactsSize == accountContactsSize && leadContactsSize > 0) {
                    System.debug('Dilyan777 ');
                    // compare the elements of the lists only if their size is the same
                    for(Contact ldContact :leadContacts) {
                        String leadEmail = ldContact.Email;
                        System.debug('leadEmail1 ' + leadEmail);                
                        leadEmail = normalizeEmail(leadEmail);
                        System.debug('leadEmail2 ' + leadEmail);
                        for(Merchant_To_Contact__c merchantToContact :accountContacts) {
                            String merchantEmail = merchantToContact.Email__c;
                            System.debug('merchantEmail1 ' + merchantEmail);                    
                            merchantEmail = normalizeEmail(merchantEmail);
                            System.debug('merchantEmail2 ' + merchantEmail);
                            if(merchantEmail.equals(leadEmail)) {
                                System.debug('merchantEmail ' + merchantEmail + 'leadEmail ' + leadEmail);
                                List<Account> accountStatus = [SELECT Status__c FROM Account where id =:objAccount.id];
                                String accountId = merchantToContact.Merchant_Name__c;
                                if(accountStatus.size() > 0) {
                                    if(!accountStatus.equals('Cancelled') && !accountStatus.equals('Lost Prospect') && !accountStatus.equals('Rejected by Acquirer') && !accountStatus.equals('Rejected by eMerchantPay') && !accountStatus.equals('Terminated')){
                                        leadObj.Status__c = 'Existing Deal';
                                        update leadObj;                                        
                                        System.debug('leadObj77 ' + leadObj);                                            
                                        System.debug('acc44 ' + accountId);
                                        System.debug('3. Lead status is set to Existing Deal');
                                        System.debug('merchantEmail3 ' + merchantEmail);
                                        // if any of the emails for lead contacts coincide with any of the emails for the account contacts return true
                                        return accountId;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    return accountId;
                                }   
                            }
                        }                
                    }
                }   
            }
        }    
        // the lead should be converted to merchant
        return '';
    }

    public PageReference convertOrRedirect() {
           // System.debug('objLead ' + objLead);
           String convertToMerchant = '/lead/leadconvert.jsp?retURL=%2F' + objLead.id + '&id=' + objLead.id + '&nooppti=0&nooverride=1';
           PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(convertToMerchant);
           pageRef.setRedirect(True);
           List<Lead> leadList = [SELECT name, id, company, website from Lead where id = :objLead.id];           
           if(leadList.size() > 0) {
               objLead = leadList.get(0);
               String objLeadId = objLead.id;
               System.debug('objLead ' + objLead); 
               String accountId = leadStatusExistingDeal(objLead);
               System.debug('accountId '  + accountId);

               if(accountId == null || accountId.equals('')) {
                   System.debug('pageRef ' + pageRef);
                   return pageRef;
               } else {
                   // List<Account> accountList = [SELECT name, id from Account where id = :accountId];
                   // if (accountList.size() > 0) {                       
                       // Account objAccount = accountList.get(0);
                       // boolean isCompareContact = compareContact(objLead, objAccount);                    
                       // System.debug('isCompareContact ' + isCompareContact);
                       // if(isCompareContact) {
                           System.debug('Dilyan34 ');
                           String doNotConvertToMerchant = '/apex/newConvToMerch';
                           pageRef = new PageReference(doNotConvertToMerchant);
                           pageRef.getParameters().put('LeadId', objLeadId);
                           pageRef.getParameters().put('AccId', accountId);
                           pageRef.setRedirect(True);
                           return pageRef;
                       // }    
                   // }
               }     
            }
            return pageRef;
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the entire exception to understand where the error is? The error may well be in your controller, not on your test...

Comment: Dylan pls share your `LeadToMerchantController` class

Comment: Hi, I've shared the implementation of the controller class. Let me know if there is anything else you need.

Comment: I'd guess zenddesk has a trigger which requires a certain field to be populated,. Their code should probably handle that better. You probably can get more insight by contacting their support.

Comment: i'd poplulate more fields on the contact to see if that makes a difference, including already having an account parent for your contact.